# How to get the desired output by modifying string after removing / from string

Tags: c#, string, date, replace

I have a string like this: 
`30/04/2018`     `o/p=300418` 
 
`01/03/2017`     `o/p=010317`
`10/11/2018`     `o/p=101118`
`12/11/2123`     `o/p=121123` 
`1/1/2018`   `o/p =010118` 
code tried but can't  get the last one 1/1/2018

```
string a = "31/04/2018";
string b = a.Replace("/","");
   b = b.Remove(4, 2);
```

Comment: written in the Question only !!

Comment: i have given 5 cases !!

Comment: Seems like you should parse these strings into DateTime's then use the `.ToString()` overload with a formatter

Comment: Also, the first date isnt a valid example `"31/04/2018"`

Answer (score 3):

You should parse to a `DateTime` and then use the `ToString` to go back to a string. The following works with your given input.

```
var dateStrings = new []{"30/04/2018", "01/03/2017","10/11/2018","12/11/2123","1/1/2018"};
foreach(var ds in dateStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(ds, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("ddMMyy"));
}
```

The only change I made is to the first date as that is not a valid date within that month (April has 30 days, not 31). If that is going to be a problem then you should change it to `TryParse` instead, currently I assumed your example was faulty and not your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure varies, all of the examples above use two digit month and day, while the bottom only uses a single digit month and day.  Your current code basically will replace the slash with an empty string, but when you remove index four to two your output would deviate.

The simplest approach would be:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("...");
var filter = $"o/p = {date:MMddyyyy}";
```

Obviously you may have to validate and ensure accuracy of your date conversion, but I don't know how your applications works.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reasonably expect that the passed in dates are *actual* dates (hint: there are only 30 days in April) you should make a function that parses the string into DateTimes, then uses string formats to get the output how you want:

```
public static string ToDateTimeFormat(string input)
{
    DateTime output;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(input, out output))
    {
        return output.ToString("MMddyy");
    }
    return input; //parse fails, return original input
}
```

My example will still take "bad" dates, but it will not throw an exception like some of the other answers given here (`TryParse()` vs `Parse()`).

There is obviously a *small* bit of overhead with parsing but its negligible compared to all the logic you would need to get the proper string manipulation.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/exBazG)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string as DateTime. Then run `ToString` with the format you desire.

```
var a = "1/1/2018";
var date = DateTime.Parse(a);
var result = date.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParseExact` to parse the input, then use `ToString` to format the output.

For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var testData = new List<string>
    {
        "31/04/2018",
        "01/03/2017",
        "10/11/2018",
        "12/11/2123",
        "1/1/2018",
    };

    foreach (var data in testData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(data, "d/m/yyyy", null).ToString("ddmmyy"));
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: How are you even getting that output? April has 30 days, the `ParseExact` call should throw an exception.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that! Very strange...it even works for February, but fails if I put in `32`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether these are DateTime values or just strings that look like date time values.  I'll assume these are DateTime values.

Convert the string to a DateTime.  Then use a string formatter.  It's important to specify the culture.  In this case `dd/mm/yyyy` is common in the UK.

```
    var culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");//UK uses the datetime format dd/MM/yyyy

    var dates = new List<string>{"30/04/2018", "01/03/2017","10/11/2018","12/11/2123","1/1/2018"};

    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        //TODO:  Do something with these values
        DateTime.Parse(date, culture).ToString("ddMMyyyy");
    }
```

Otherwise, running `DateTime.Parse` on a machine with a different culture could result in a `FormatException`.  [Parsing dates and times in .NET.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime)